# Manipulate array with react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Say I have a component that gets an array, and I want to do some logic:

```
const MyComponent = ({ myArray = [] }) => {
  console.log("infinite rendering");
  const [prop, setProp] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    setProp(myArray.map(x => x + 1))
  }, [myArray])

  return <div />
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/x3kq907r5z

The problem is I get an infinite loop.

I can fix the bug by removing the default value `({ myArray })` and checking if array `if (Array.isArray(myArray)) setProp(...)`

But I'm struggling to understand: 
What is the best way of doing any sort of manipulation to a prop (array/object/etc) using hooks?

Comment: I don't really get what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Is this what you tried to achieve ? https://codesandbox.io/s/826v2qn9r0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the way your code is written currently, `myArray` is a different instance of an empty array on every render. This means that the effect always gets run, as the dependencies have always changed!

This might seem weird, but consider the following piece of code:

```js
const a = [];
const b = [];
console.log(a === b); // false
```

The simplest fixes for this would be to either move the fallback logic into the effect:

```js
const MyComponent = ({ myArray }) => {
  console.log("infinite rendering");
  const [prop, setProp] = useState([]);
  useEffect(
    () => {
      setProp(myArray ? myArray.map(x => x + 1) : []);
    },
    [myArray]
  );

  return <div />;
};
```

Or ensure the same empty array always gets used as the default:

```js
const empty = [];
const MyComponent = ({ myArray = empty }) => {
  console.log("infinite rendering");
  const [prop, setProp] = useState([]);
  useEffect(
    () => {
      setProp(myArray.map(x => x + 1));
    },
    [myArray]
  );

  return <div />;
};
```

Comment: Your answer plus `const empty = [];` solution went as a life vest after 4 hours fighting React. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> But I'm struggling to understand: What is the best way of doing any sort of manipulation to a prop (array/object/etc) using hooks?

Hooks are great when you are trying manipulate a local state value, not a prop. You define a state with useState(), and you use useEffect() or other event handlers to update the value.

The prop is being changed *outside* of the component, which triggers the functional component to re-execute. So, to answer your question: you don't manipulate props with hooks. The best you can do is to prevent rendering when props change with useMemo(), but that's a different topic.

Having said that, your example can just become:

```
const MyComponent = ({ myArray = [] }) => {

    console.log("runs when myArray changes");

    const newArray = myArray.map(x => x + 1);

  return <div />
}
```